# Return specific header in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to return the authorization key from my discord account trough a javascript snippet. Previously how I would get the token is by opening chrome developers tools Go to Network type in 'api/v6' reload the page select 'library' then click on headers and scroll down and it would show token:(token).

I tried to return this with javascript but I don't seem to get the return i need

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open('GET', document.location, false);
req.send(null);
var headers = req.getAllResponseHeaders('library').toLowerCase();
alert(headers);
```

I expect to get something like

```
 :authority: discordapp.com
 :method: GET
 :path: /api/v6/users/@me/library
 :scheme: https
 accept: */*
 accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
 accept-language: nl
 authorization: (token)
```

Instead i get returned

```
date: wed, 13 feb 2019 10:58:38 gmt
content-encoding: br
server: gws
x-frame-options: sameorigin
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
status: 200
cache-control: private
alt-svc: quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="44,43,39"
x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
expires: wed, 13 feb 2019 10:58:38 gmt
```

Comment: Read the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders) you don't pass string to getAllResponseHeaders and it return string of all headers, you need parse it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to parse the string:

```
 let arr = headers.trim().split(/[\r\n]+/);
```

After that, you can use destructuring assignment from that response. Something like:

```
let {authorization, path, ...} = arr;
```

Comment: This will not work because headers is single string. See the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getAllResponseHeaders)

Comment: I edited my question the snippet i had doesn't return the token at all it just returns some other headers

Comment: To get a token in your response you need to make a get request to the discord authorization server with your credentials.

Answer (score 0):

`getAllResponseHeaders` returns all the headers. You need the method `getResponseHeader` to get a specific header.

So your code would become:

```
var headers = req.getResponseHeader('library').toLowerCase();
```

See [documentation here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/getResponseHeader).

Comment: I edited my question the snippet i had doesn't return the token at all it just returns some other headers

Answer (score 0):

You are using a function called `getAllResponseHeaders` but the headers you say you expect are **request** headers (sent from the browser to the server) — along with some other information about the request which aren't headers at all —, not **response** headers (sent from the server to the browser).

There is no API provided to inspect the outgoing headers through XMLHttpRequest (or fetch).

If you want to know what they are, you'll need to write server-side code to echo them back to the client.

Comment: Then how is chrome able to see them in the network console?

Comment: @MrKushy — Because Chrome is sending the headers and provides more access to them in the developer tools (which can only be accessed by the user of the browser) then it does to JavaScript from Joe Random's website.